# Overfull \vbox when starting new subsection and subsubsection near bottom of the page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, warnings

I ran into this issue when writing up a document, and I don't see an obvious, elegant way to fix it.  I could add a `\clearpage` after the figure, but as the document changes I'll have to revisit that `\clearpage`.

I'll try to reduce the example as best as I can.

[image: Sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=31pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt
\end{minipage}\par}%

\renewcommand\headrule{
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize
\end{minipage}}%

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\huge\textbf{Lorem}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textcopyright\ \the\year\ Ipsum Inc.}
\fancyfoot[R]{ABC1234-page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Draft}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Lorem}
\lipsum[2-5]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

\end{multicols}

\def\degr{${}^\circ$}

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \captionof{figure}{Dolor Timing}
    \label{fig:dolor}
    \begin{framed}
        \begin{tikztimingtable}
            Lorem   &  L 8{C}          2{L} 3{C} G ;[ dotted ] C; 4{C} 2{L} 10{C}                           ;[ dotted ] 2L  ; 12{C}                                       2{L} 8{C} \\
            Ipsum   &  2{L} 2D{1} 5{L} 2{L} 3{L}   ;[ dotted ] L; 4{L} 2{X} 2D{LSb} 2D{1} 2D{2} 2D{3} 2D{4} ;[ dotted ] 2D{}; 2D{10} 2D{11} 2D{12} 2D{13} 2D{14} 2D{MSb} 10{L}      \\
        \end{tikztimingtable}
    \end{framed}
\end{minipage}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsection{Lorem}
\subsubsection{Dolor}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give `multicol` a bit of help by using the optional argument to tell it how much space it needs before deciding to force a page break at the start.

Two possibilities, depending if you want the image at the end of the page or the start of the next

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\showoutput
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=31pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt
\end{minipage}\par}%

\renewcommand\headrule{%%%
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize
\end{minipage}}%

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\huge\textbf{Lorem}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textcopyright\ \the\year\ Ipsum Inc.}
\fancyfoot[R]{ABC1234-page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Draft}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Lorem}
\lipsum[2-5]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}[{%
\def\degr{${}^\circ$}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
    \captionof{figure}{Dolor Timing}
    \label{fig:dolor}
    \begin{framed}
        \begin{tikztimingtable}
            Lorem   &  L 8{C}          2{L} 3{C} G ;[ dotted ] C; 4{C} 2{L} 10{C}                           ;[ dotted ] 2L  ; 12{C}                                       2{L} 8{C} \\
            Ipsum   &  2{L} 2D{1} 5{L} 2{L} 3{L}   ;[ dotted ] L; 4{L} 2{X} 2D{LSb} 2D{1} 2D{2} 2D{3} 2D{4} ;[ dotted ] 2D{}; 2D{10} 2D{11} 2D{12} 2D{13} 2D{14} 2D{MSb} 10{L}      \\
        \end{tikztimingtable}
    \end{framed}
\end{minipage}}][20\baselineskip]



\subsection{Lorem}

\subsubsection{Dolor}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\showoutput
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=31pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\footrule{\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt
\end{minipage}\par}%

\renewcommand\headrule{%%%
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize
\end{minipage}}%

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\huge\textbf{Lorem}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textcopyright\ \the\year\ Ipsum Inc.}
\fancyfoot[R]{ABC1234-page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{Draft}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Lorem}
\lipsum[2-5]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.

\end{multicols}


\def\degr{${}^\circ$}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
    \captionof{figure}{Dolor Timing}
    \label{fig:dolor}
    \begin{framed}
        \begin{tikztimingtable}
            Lorem   &  L 8{C}          2{L} 3{C} G ;[ dotted ] C; 4{C} 2{L} 10{C}                           ;[ dotted ] 2L  ; 12{C}                                       2{L} 8{C} \\
            Ipsum   &  2{L} 2D{1} 5{L} 2{L} 3{L}   ;[ dotted ] L; 4{L} 2{X} 2D{LSb} 2D{1} 2D{2} 2D{3} 2D{4} ;[ dotted ] 2D{}; 2D{10} 2D{11} 2D{12} 2D{13} 2D{14} 2D{MSb} 10{L}      \\
        \end{tikztimingtable}
    \end{framed}
\end{minipage}

\begin{multicols}{2}[][5\baselineskip]

\subsection{Lorem}
\subsubsection{Dolor}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to be an issue with multicol.  Is there a global setting I'm missing, or do I need to do this for every place where there's an issue.

Comment: At any rate, I think I prefer the second, if only for the simpler syntax.  And in most cases text referring to the figure is likely to come before.

Comment: @RyanB you can increase the length `\premulticols` to whatever you want the minimum distance between start of multcols and the bottom of the page, that is the default value for the argument

Answer (score 1):

If you are not forced to have text of the same height on all pages, you can simply write `\raggedbottom` (somewhere) after `\begin{document}`.  Standard behaviour is defined by `\flushbottom`.

Comment: FYI This doesn't resolve the issue for either the example or the project I'm working on.